# show all fields of table alias in google big query with a join statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query with a simple join statement and i want to print all the field of one table.

```
select t1.id, t1.field1, ..., t1.fieldN
from first_table as t1
join second_table as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.field1 = "some value"
```

Can i build in some way (or does a shortcut exist) the select statement with the * wildcard?

```
select t1.*
from first_table as t1
join second_table as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.field1 = "some value"
```

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: having all the (t1) table field in the output, selecting them with a wild card and not one by one.

Comment: It sounds like Mikhail's answer worked for you. In general, try to stick to standard SQL to avoid surprising behavior with field names and aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use BigQuery Legacy SQL with joins as in you second query in post - you are getting your output fields prefixed with table alias as t1_id, t1_field1 and so on

Instead please use BigQuery Standard SQL which does not have this behavior

Just try

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.*
FROM first_table AS t1
JOIN second_table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.field1 = "some value"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , your solutions work fine. FYI Just using t1.* doesn't prevent the prefix in the alias - t1_id / t1_field1 / etc